# SQL Query - Identifying entries between payment dates greater than 6 years

Tags: sql, date, payment, azure-data-lake, date-difference

I have this table (in reality it has more fields but for simplicity, it will demonstrate what I'm after)

| Payment_Type | Person ID | Payment_date | Payment_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Normal | 1 | 2015-01-01 | £1.00 |
| Normal | 1 | 2017-01-01 | £2.00 |
| Reversal | 1 | 2022-01-09 | £3.00 |
| Normal | 2 | 2016-12-29 | £3.00 |
| Reversal | 2 | 2022-01-02 | £4.00 |

**I need 2 specific things from this:**

I need all entries where there is over 6 years difference between any given payment dates (when its been greater than or equal to 6 years from the date of the latest payment date). I don't need to count them, I just need it to return all the entries that meet this criteria.

I also need it to specify where a normal payment hasn't been made for 6 years or more from todays date but a reversal has however occurred within the last 6 years. (This might need to be a separate query but will take suggestions)

I'm using Data Lake (Hue).

Thank you.

I've tried to run a sub query with join and union but I'm not getting the desired results so will need to start from scratch. Any advice/insight on this is greatly appreciated.

Ideally, query one will show:

| Payment_Type | Person ID | Payment_date | Payment_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Normal | 1 | 2015-01-01 | £1.00 |
| Normal | 1 | 2017-01-01 | £2.00 |
| Normal | 2 | 2016-12-29 | £3.00 |

Query 2 results should show:

| Payment_Type | Person ID | Payment_date | Payment_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Normal | 1 | 2017-01-01 | £2.00 |
| Reversal | 1 | 2022-01-09 | £3.00 |
| Normal | 2 | 2016-12-29 | £3.00 |
| Reversal | 2 | 2022-01-02 | £4.00 |

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images or links to images. Make it easy to assist you! [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Apologies, this is my first post. Updated to reflect feedback, DBMS is through DataLake (Hue/Hadoop) - Date format is YYYY-MM-DD.